# About int and unsigned int

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, signed-integer, internal-representation

There are the following programs：

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i=2147483647;
   unsigned int j=4294967295;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",i,i+1,i+2);
   printf("%u %u %u\n",j,j+1,j+2);
   return 0;
}
```

Why i+2 is not equal to -2147483646 ?

why j+2 is not equal to 2

It's the result that I expected was different. What is its execution process like?

**EDIT**

The result I get is:

- i=2147483647
- i+1=-2147483648
- i+2=-2147483647
- j=4294967295
- j+1=0
- j+2=1

Comment: What is the actual result you get?

Comment: Signed integer arithmetic overflow leads to *undefined behavior*. As long as you have UB, specilation about the behavior of your whole program is rather moot.

Comment: The result I get is: 

 i=2147483647 ,  

i+1=-2147483648 ,  

i+2=-2147483647,   

 j=4294967295,   

j+1= 0 ,   

j+2=1

Comment: @fuyingwei, you should add that to the question instead of writing it in the comments.

Comment: You are assuming that `int` is always 32 bits in size. You should not.

Comment: The results you are getting are correct, if we assume common wrap-around. Please explain in the question why you expect these other values.

Comment: Speculating about *some* (well-defined) behavior: The unsigned arithmetic overflow. You have the hexadecimal value `0xffffffff` and then you add `1` making it wrap over to `0x00000000`. When you add `2` it wraps over to `0x00000001`. What else did you expect?

Comment: And while really UB, the same really happens for the signed integer arithmetic overflow. You have hexadecimal `0x7fffffff` and then add `1` which becomes `0x80000000` which indeed is `-2147483648` in two's complement. And `0x7fffffff` plus `2` then becomes `0x80000001` which is `-2147483647`.

Comment: Regarding the values you expect, why do you expect those values? What is the reasoning behind your expectations?

Comment: Why should `j+2` be `2` if `j!=0`?

Comment: I understand，thanks all  !!!

Answer (score 2):

If you will output the value of `j` in the hexadecimal notation like for example

```
unsigned int j = UINT_MAX;
printf( "j = %u, j = %#x\n", j, j );
```

You will get the following output

```
j = 4294967295, j = 0xffffffff
```

So adding `1` to `0xffffffff` you will get `0x00000000`. Again adding `1` you will get `0x00000001`.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 9. ... A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because
>    a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>    type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>    value that can be represented by the resulting type.

As for the signed integer variable `i` then in general the result is undefined due to the overflow.

If the internal representation of integers is two's complement representation then implementations can silently wrap-around on overflow. In this case for signed integer you will have

```
int i = INT_MAX;

printf( "i = %d, i = %#x\n", i, ( unsigned int )i );
printf( "i + 1 = %d, i + 1 = %#x\n", i + 1, ( unsigned int )( i + 1 ) );
printf( "i + 2 = %d, i + 2 = %#x\n", i + 2, ( unsigned int )( i + 2 ) );
```

The output is

```
i = 2147483647, i = 0x7fffffff
i + 1 = -2147483648, i + 1 = 0x80000000
i + 2 = -2147483647, i + 2 = 0x80000001
```

That is the hexadecimal representation of an object of the type int `0x80000000` yields the minimal value stored in the object (the sign bit is set). The representation `0x80000001` yields the value that follows the minimal value.

Comment: I still don't quite understand

Comment: @fuyingwei Consider the hexadecimal output of the code provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

according to your question i think that you know why i+1=-2147483648
so i + 2 = 2147483647 + 2 = -2147483647 it's not -2147483648 + 2
the same thing about second question

Comment: Isn't it initialized to 0 if overflow?